# CSRF in local development

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I have an app where the frontend is using React and the backend is using django-rest-framework. The backend enforces CSRF which is needed, and I think everything will work fine in production because the backend and the frontend will share the same origin (https://mydomain.awesome).

But for local development I have a problem, my frontend is running on localhost:3000 and my backend is running on localhost:8000, and this means they are on different origins and my backend is not sending CSRF token to my frontend.

What do people do in this case? How can I have "same origin" in the local development environment?

Comment: did you add `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in your middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a package called [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

`pip install django-cors-headers`.

Then, in your Django project's `settings.py`, include the following line at the top of the MIDDLEWARE section:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ... (other middlware)
]
```

Now, add the following lines in your `settings.py`:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
  "http://localhost:3000",
  "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
]
```

This makes it so that the frontend is allowed to make requests to your backend by using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

If you need to pass along cookies (e.g. csrf token, credential tokens) with the request from your frontend to the server, additionally add the following line:

`CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`

Then, you would have to set up your request client on the frontend. I personally use `axios`:

```
const response = await axios.post(url, { ...data }, { withCredentials: true })
```